# error con datagridview C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema al intentar correr este código, lo que intento  hacer es que en la columna 9 se tome en cuenta la "," y el ".", el código es el siguiente:

```cs
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+textBox1.Text+";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");

OleDbDataAdapter da= new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Hoja1$]", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.Columns[9].ValueType = typeof(decimal);
dataGridView1.Columns[9].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = ci;
dataGridView1.Columns[9].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

El error que me envía es el siguiente:

> index was out of range. Must be non- negative and less than the size
>   of the collection.

La tabla contiene 18 columnas, así que no sé por qué me aparece este error.

Comment: No olvides el indice 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a que tu dataset ya genera el esquema del datagrid por lo que no es necesario redefinir el esquema, solamente en tu datagridview genera el siguiente evento:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "NombreDeColumnaAFormatear")
        {
            e.CellStyle.Format = "N2"; //Formato como N2, C4, etc.
        }
    }
```

**Nota:** El nombre de la columna vendria siendo el nombre proveniente del encabezado de tu consulta de sql